# coin change problem in pl sql. Convert c++ logic in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to convert this logic in plsql. using oracle. I have done this code in c++ but i am facing problem while doing it in plsql.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void coinChange(vector<int>& v, vector<int>& v1, int& a) {
        int p;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if(a % v[i] != 0 && a >= v[i]) {
                p = a / v[i];
                if(p > v1[i]) {
                    a = a - (v[i] * v1[i]);
                    p = v1[i];
                    v[i] = p;
                } else {
                    a = a % v[i];
                    v[i] = p;
                }
            } else if( a % v[i] == 0 && a >= v[i]) {
                p = a / v[i];
                if(p > v[i]) {
                    a = a - (v[i] * v1[i]);
                    p = v1[i];
                    v[i] = p;
                } else {
                    a = 0;
                    v[i] = p;
                }
            } else if(a < v[i] || a == 0) {
                v[i] = 0;
            }
            cout<<v[i]<<"&&&&&"<<endl;
        }

    }
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> v1;
    int a;
    cout<<"enter amount";
    cin>>a;
    int m;
    cout<<"enter no. of coins";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"enter coins";
    int n;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m; i++) {
        cin>>n;
        v.push_back(n);
    }
    cout<<"enter no. of each coin";
    int o;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m; i++) {
        cin>>o;
        v1.push_back(o);
    }
    coinChange(v,v1,a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a problem of coin change , the output which I want is how to return the change with given coins of 10,5 and 1. This code is the solution but just want to convert it into plsql.

Comment: While some problems make sense to solve in PL/SQL, generic tasks like this one doesn't. Why do you need to do it in PL/SQL?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). As well as read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Stack Overflow isn't a translation-service, show us your attempt and describe your problems with it.

Comment: Keep your logic in your application and your data in your database

Comment: By the way your `else if( a % v[i] == 0 && a >= v[i]) {`-case is redundant, you can just check for `if(a >= v[i]) {` and use first if-case. No need to destinuish between 0 and != 0 here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because its a requirement

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language; it is appropriate to solve this sort of problem in PL/SQL. If we were talking about SQL (rather than PL/SQL) then it would be a different problem; not an impossible one but you would be fighting the language to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it passing two SQL collections into a procedure; however, its so much easier if you create an object type that contains the coin value and amount.

It is also much easier to understand code if your variables have meaningful names.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE coin_amount IS OBJECT(
  value  NUMBER(6,2),
  amount NUMBER(5,0)
);
/

CREATE TYPE coin_amount_list IS TABLE OF coin_amount;
/
```

**PL/SQL**:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE coinChange(
  i_coin_amounts IN coin_amount_list,
  i_change       IN NUMBER
)
IS
  p_sorted_coin_amounts coin_amount_list;
  coin                  NUMBER(6,2);
  amount                NUMBER(5,0);
  remaining_change      NUMBER(6,2) := i_change;
BEGIN
  SELECT   coin_amount( value, SUM( amount ) )
  BULK COLLECT INTO p_sorted_coin_amounts
  FROM     TABLE( i_coin_amounts )
  WHERE    value  > 0
  AND      amount > 0
  GROUP BY value
  ORDER BY value DESC;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Change for:  ' || TO_CHAR( remaining_change, 'L9990D00' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '-------------------------------' );

  FOR i IN 1 .. p_sorted_coin_amounts.COUNT LOOP
    coin   := p_sorted_coin_amounts(i).value;
    amount := LEAST( FLOOR( remaining_change / coin ), p_sorted_coin_amounts(i).amount );
    IF amount > 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '    ' || TO_CHAR( amount, '99990' ) || ' x ' || TO_CHAR( coin, 'L9990D00' ) );
      remaining_change := remaining_change - coin * amount;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '-------------------------------' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Outstanding: ' || TO_CHAR( remaining_change, 'L9990D00' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '-------------------------------' );
END;
/
```

**Testing**:

```sql
BEGIN
  coinChange(
    coin_amount_list(
      coin_amount( 0.05, 50 ),
      coin_amount( 0.10, 15 ),
      coin_amount( 0.01,  5 )
    ),
    2.57
  );
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> Change for:               $2.57
> -------------------------------
>         15 x              $0.10
>         21 x              $0.05
>          2 x              $0.01
> -------------------------------
> Outstanding:              $0.00
> -------------------------------
> ```

and

```sql
BEGIN
  coinChange(
    coin_amount_list(
      coin_amount( 0.20, 4 ),
      coin_amount( 1.00, 5 ),
      coin_amount( 0.20, 4 ),
      coin_amount( 0.02, 1 )
    ),
    6.33
  );
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> Change for:               $6.33
> -------------------------------
>          5 x              $1.00
>          6 x              $0.20
>          1 x              $0.02
> -------------------------------
> Outstanding:              $0.11
> -------------------------------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9841cbac019526833fcb7cd4e7c4e22)*